# Android Studio inspection profile doesn't contain all the rules

Tags: android, android-studio, android-lint

It seems to me that Android Studio inspection profile doesn't allow me to choose the same inspection that is used by Gradle command `./gradlew lint`.

I'm interested in running "LiveData value assignment nullability mismatch" (the one that can be suppressed by using `@SuppressLint("NullSafeMutableLiveData")`) and I can do it using the "Run inspection by name..." in Android Studio:

[image: Android Studio option - run inspection by name]

[image: Android Studio showing the "LiveData value assignment nullability mismatch" inspection]

But when I try to create an inspection profile with that specific inspection, I can't find it:

[image: Android Studio inspection profile with an empty search result]

[image: Android Studio inspection profile with the specific inspection missing on the list]

Do you know how it can be enabled?